# Relative path %~dp0..\ was unexpected?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, path, relative-path

I am trying to run a .bat file which contains this particular line:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:, " %%a in ('findstr /R /C:"\"electronVersion\":.*" %~dp0..\package.json') do set npm_config_target=%%~a
```

However, I get this error instead on both cmd.exe and PowerShell:

> ```
> \vscode\scripts\..\package.json') was unexpected at this time.
> ```

Seems like the double dot in the relative file path is not working.
How do I fix this?

Comment: The statement should work AFAICS. Did you try putting the path in double quotes (`"%~dp0..\package.json"`)?

Comment: Thanks, it worked!